# Customising column sort order in v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an array auditResult(the data came from response.data.data) that have value like
-internalID
-fieldName
-OldValue
-NewValue

I have a table

```html
  <v-data-table :items="auditResults" :headers="headers" class="searchable sortable">
    <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td>{{ getCodeValue(props.item.codeid) }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.fieldname }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.oldvalue }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.newvalue }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.requestedwhen | formatDate }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.changedappliedwhen | formatDate }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.requestedby }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.reasonforchange }}</td>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:no-results>
      <v-alert :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">Found no results.</v-alert>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

Now I have a method called getCodeValue where the internalID is compared to Code to get the Code Value
here is the code:

```js
getCodeValue(codeid) {
  let codeFound = this.codeResults.find(m => m.internalid == codeid);
  if (codeFound) {
    this.auditResults.codeid = codeFound.code;
    return this.auditResults.codeid;
  }
  return "Code not found";
}
```

Now my problem is instead the Code will be sorted the table is using the internalID to sort it. Reason being is the table item is auditResult.

How can I achieve that the table should sort the Code from getCodeValue method and not the internalID from auditResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   formatMember(){
  let newMembers = this.auditResults.slice();
  newMembers.map((el) => (el.codeid = this.getCodeValue(el.codeid)));
  return newMembers;
}
```

I got it. So no need to manual sort the data and we can change the property of our data model in computed component. This works for me 100%.

In my vuetify table instead of auditResult I changed it to formatMember. Meaning the table is using the computed method to get the array object.

```
    <v-data-table
    :items="formatMember"
    :headers="headers"
    class="searchable sortable"
  >
```

Hope this will help others in future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can give a `v-data-table` your own function to use to compare rows by passing `sort` option in header definition

In headers:

```js
headers: [
    {
        text: 'Code',
        value: 'codeid',
        sort: function(a, b) {
            // implement custom compare function here
        },
    },
],
```

Function passed to `sort` should implement same "contract" as used in [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

1. return 0 if items are equal
2. return -1 if a < b (a comes first)
3. return +1 if a > b (b comes first)

Some notes:

1. `this.auditResults.codeid = codeFound.code;` - `auditResults` is an array so you are adding new property to your array instance, not changing value of `codeid` in your object inside the array
2. I don't recommend doing such thing anyway. Your function is called for every row **every time the template is re-rendering** so you will end up with "Code not found" value in every row eventually
3. You should probably add new property (with value looked up by your function) into your data objects once ([beware of Vue's Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)) after you receive your data from API instead of looking up the value every time. Then you will not need any custom sorting or custom rendering logic...

Comment: headers: [
          {text: 'Code ID',value: 'codeid', sort: function (a,b) {const sortBy = this.currentSort
          if (this.currentSortOrder === 'desc') {
            return a[sortBy].localeCompare(b[sortBy])
          }
          return b[sortBy].localeCompare(a[sortBy])}},

I tried this but still im getting the same result

Comment: Because with this code you are still using `codeid` field. You need to understand that code in your question __is not adding__ new property into your data object. It just changes how it is rendered on the screen. That's why i suggest to add new property (computed by your lookup function) 1st before passing it to `v-data-table`. Then you will not need any custom sorting or custom rendering logic...

Comment: I actually understand that it's not adding new property. I just dont know how to use the new value from converted Value. 
I will try to create new property.

Comment: How can I add the new property to table ? my table accept item from auditResult only correct ?

Comment: I would not recommend sorting directly in your component. Instead sort the items in auditResults inside your store and pass it to your component.

Comment: Sort the items in auditResult ? U mean manual sorting? How can I achieve that like data : [ {auditResult : [sort here?] },

Comment: @Ckuessner Doesn't sound like a good idea to me. Sorting (in some kind of table on screen) is clearly presentation/view concern. Vuex/store handles state management concern. Why would you do your life that much complicated? Doesn't make sense. "Just put everything inside Vuex" seems like some kind of illness in Vue community to me. He's clearly not using Vuex anyway....

Comment: im still getting the same result. anyone has some good approach ?